# CakePHP User levels?

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I am developing an authentication system in CakePHP. I have two kind of users; Applicant and Employer. I have a User table and controllers, models and views for each of them:

```
controllers:
    users_controller.php
    applicants_controller.php
    employers_controller.php

models:
    user.php
    applicant.php
    employer.php

views:
    applicants:
        register.ctp
    employers:
        register.ctp
```

In this way, when I want to register an Applicant I use the Applicant controller, model and register view. The same for the Employer. But I am repeating myself. What is the best way to implement this? Should I use ACL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are your only differences I would go with just one User-table and only set flags accordingly.

For this you would need 2 more table-fields called `applicant` and `employee`. Just use `tinyint(1)` so Cake can use it as boolean value.

In your AppController you then can check (after authing with the [AuthComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication)) for these two values and allow or deny actions.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It is a good hint, but what if in the future my application must support multiple login protocols like OpenID? That's one reason I want to split the tables, but so far my implementation is not good enough. What should I do to not breach the DRY principle?

Comment: I don't see why want to split tables for multiple login protocols. But if you want so keep your current implementation you should read the manual about Components (code shared for controllers) and Behaviors (code shared for models). That should get you on the right track.